# Mocking an autowired object of base abstract class

Tags: spring, junit, mockito, abstract-class, autowired

I'm writing the Junit test case for a class which is extended by an abstract class. This base abstract class has an autowired object of a different class which is being used in the class I'm testing. 
I'm trying to mock in the subclass, but the mocked object is throwing a NullPointerException.

Example:

```java
// class I am testing
public class GetTransactionsForProcessorGroupActivity extends GetTransactionsBaseActivity {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(GetTransactionsForProcessorGroupActivity.class);

    public GetTransactionsForProcessorGroupActivity(ARHFactory arhFactory, MetricsFactory metricsFactory) {
        super(arhFactory, metricsFactory);
    }


    @Override
    protected List<OverseasTransaction> getOverseasTransactions(Document herdDocument)
            throws IllegalDateFormatException, ProcessorConfigurationException, DocumentException {
        final String paymentProcessorGroup = HerdDocumentUtils.getPaymentProcessor(herdDocument);
        final Date runDate = HerdDocumentUtils.getRunDate(herdDocument);

        final List<String> paymentProcessorList = ProcessorGroupLookup.getProcessorsFromGroup(paymentProcessorGroup);
        List<OverseasTransaction> overseasTransactionList = new ArrayList<OverseasTransaction>();
        List<ProcessorTransactionWindow> processingWindows = new ArrayList<ProcessorTransactionWindow>();

        for (final String processor : paymentProcessorList) {
            ProcessorTransactionWindow transactionWindow = ProcessorCalendarUtils.getProcessorTransactionWindow(processor, runDate);
            processingWindows.add(transactionWindow);

            final Date processingFromDate = transactionWindow.getFromDate();
            final Date processingToDate = transactionWindow.getToDate();
//NullpointerException on this line, as OverseasTransactionStore mock object returns null.
            final List<OverseasTransaction> transactions = overseasTransactionsStore
                    .queryOverseasTransactionsOnPPTimelineandDates(processor, processingFromDate, processingToDate);
            overseasTransactionList.addAll(transactions);
        }

        HerdDocumentUtils.putProcessingWindowDetails(herdDocument, processingWindows);
        return overseasTransactionList;
    }

}

// Base class
public abstract class GetTransactionsBaseActivity extends CoralHerdActivity implements ActionRequestHandler {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(GetTransactionsBaseActivity.class);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static final Map<String, String> S3_CONFIGURATION = AppConfig.findMap(Constants.S3_CONFIGURATION_KEY);
    private static final String S3_BUCKET = S3_CONFIGURATION.get(Constants.BUCKET_NAME);

    private static final class Status {
        private static final String PROCESSOR_DETAILS_NOT_FOUND = "NoPaymentProcessorDetailsPresent";
        private static final String TRANSACTIONS_OBTAINED = "TransactionsObtained";
        private static final String NO_TRANSACTIONS_TO_BE_CONSIDERED = "NoTransactionsToBeConsidered";
        private static final String NEGATIVE_OR_ZERO_AMOUNT = "NegativeOrZeroAmount";
    }

    protected final ARHFactory arhFactory;

    protected final MetricsFactory metricsFactory;

    @Autowired
    OverseasTransactionsStore overseasTransactionsStore;

    @Autowired
    S3ClientProvider s3ClientProvider;


    protected abstract List<OverseasTransaction> getOverseasTransactions(Document herdDocument)
            throws IllegalDateFormatException, ProcessorConfigurationException, DocumentException;

    @Override
    public ActionResponse postActionRequest(final ActionRequest request) throws Exception {
        TimedARH timedARH = (TimedARH) arhFactory.createARH();
        timedARH.setHandler(this);
        return timedARH.handle(request);
    }

    public ActionResponse handle(final ActionRequest request) throws Exception {
        final Document herdDocument = HerdDocumentUtils.getFundFlowDocument(request);
        final Metrics metrics = MetricsLogger.getMetrics(metricsFactory);

        final String paymentProcessor = HerdDocumentUtils.getPaymentProcessor(herdDocument);

        try {
            final List<OverseasTransaction> overseasTransactionList;
            MetricsLogger.logFundFlowExecution(metrics, paymentProcessor);

            try {
                overseasTransactionList = getOverseasTransactions(herdDocument);
            } catch (ProcessorConfigurationException e) {
                return new ActionComplete(Status.PROCESSOR_DETAILS_NOT_FOUND, herdDocument);
            }

            if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(overseasTransactionList)) {
                MetricsLogger.logTransactionMetrics(metrics, paymentProcessor, 0, BigDecimal.ZERO);
                return new ActionComplete(Status.NO_TRANSACTIONS_TO_BE_CONSIDERED, herdDocument);
            }

            final String s3ObjectKey = getS3ObjectKey(request, paymentProcessor);
            storeTransactionsInS3(overseasTransactionList, S3_BUCKET, s3ObjectKey);

            final int itemCount = overseasTransactionList.size();
            BigDecimal totalAmount = BigDecimal.ZERO;
            for (OverseasTransaction overseasTransaction : overseasTransactionList) {
                if (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(overseasTransaction.getType(), Constants.TRANSACTION_TYPE_CHARGE)) {
                    totalAmount = totalAmount.add(overseasTransaction.getOverseasAmount());
                } else if (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(overseasTransaction.getType(), Constants.TRANSACTION_TYPE_REFUND)) {
                    totalAmount = totalAmount.subtract(overseasTransaction.getOverseasAmount());
                }
            }

            MetricsLogger.logTransactionMetrics(metrics, paymentProcessor, itemCount, totalAmount);

            HerdDocumentUtils.putS3Location(herdDocument, S3_BUCKET, s3ObjectKey);
            HerdDocumentUtils.putTotalAmount(herdDocument, totalAmount);
            HerdDocumentUtils.putTransactionItemCount(herdDocument, itemCount);
            HerdDocumentUtils.putPaymentProcessor(herdDocument, paymentProcessor);

            if (totalAmount.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) <= 0) {
                log.info("Total amount to disburse is zero or negative. {}", totalAmount);
                return new ActionComplete(Status.NEGATIVE_OR_ZERO_AMOUNT, herdDocument);
            }

            return new ActionComplete(Status.TRANSACTIONS_OBTAINED, herdDocument);
        } finally {
            MetricsLogger.closeMetrics(metrics);
        }
    }

}


// Test class
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({ "javax.management.*" })
@PrepareForTest({ HerdDocumentUtils.class, ProcessorGroupLookup.class })
public class GetTransactionsForProcessorGroupActivityTest extends AppConfigInitializedTestBase {

    private static HerdInput herdInput;
    private static HerdOutput herdOutput;
    private static final String paymentProcessorGroup = "BillDesk";
    private static final String paymentProcessorGroupNotFound = "IndiaPaymentGateway";

    @Mock
    ActionRequest request;

    @Mock
    WorkItemIdentifier workItemId;

    @Mock
    private CoralHerdActivity coralHerdActivity;

    @Mock
    Metrics metrics;

    @Mock
    Map<String, String> S3_CONFIGURATION_MAP;

    @Mock
    MetricsFactory metricsFactory;

    @Mock
    ARHFactory arhFactory;

    @Mock
    Document herdDocument;

    @Mock
    OverseasTransactionsStore overseasTransactionsStore;

    @Mock
    S3ClientProvider s3ClientProvider;

//    @InjectMocks
//    GetTransactionsForProcessorGroupActivity getTransactionsBaseActivityTest;

    // new GetTransactionsForProcessorGroupActivity(arhFactory, metricsFactory);

    @Before
    public void setup() {

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(HerdDocumentUtils.class);
        // PowerMockito.mockStatic(ProcessorGroupLookup.class);
      //  GetTransactionsBaseActivity getTransactionsBaseActivity = new GetTransactionsBaseActivity(overseasTransactionsStore);

    }

    @Test
    public void testEnact() {
        GetTransactionsForProcessorGroupActivity getTransactionsForProcessorGroupActivity = Mockito
                .mock(GetTransactionsForProcessorGroupActivity.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
        Mockito.when(coralHerdActivity.enact(herdInput)).thenReturn(herdOutput);
        final HerdOutput actualHerdOutput = getTransactionsForProcessorGroupActivity.enact(herdInput);
        Assert.assertNotNull(actualHerdOutput);
    }

    @Test
    public void testgetpaymentProcessorList() throws Exception {
        Date date = new Date();
        List<String> paymentProcessorList;
        PowerMockito.when(HerdDocumentUtils.getPaymentProcessor(herdDocument)).thenReturn(paymentProcessorGroup);
        PowerMockito.when(HerdDocumentUtils.getRunDate(herdDocument)).thenReturn(date);
        paymentProcessorList = ProcessorGroupLookup.getProcessorsFromGroup(paymentProcessorGroup);
        assertNotNull(paymentProcessorList);
    }

    @Test(expected = ProcessorConfigurationException.class)
    public void testpaymentProcessorListNotFound() {
        Date date = new Date();
        PowerMockito.when(HerdDocumentUtils.getPaymentProcessor(herdDocument))
                .thenReturn(paymentProcessorGroupNotFound);
        PowerMockito.when(HerdDocumentUtils.getRunDate(herdDocument)).thenReturn(date);
        List<String> paymentProcessorList = ProcessorGroupLookup.getProcessorsFromGroup(paymentProcessorGroupNotFound);
        assertNotNull(paymentProcessorList);
    }

    @Test
    public void canGetOverseasTransactiontest() throws Exception {

        GetTransactionsForProcessorGroupActivity getTransactionsForProcessorGroupActivity = Mockito
                .mock(GetTransactionsForProcessorGroupActivity.class);
        // OverseasTransactionsStore overseasTransactionsStore =
        // Mockito.mock(OverseasTransactionsStoreImpl.class);

        Date date = new Date();
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        PowerMockito.when(HerdDocumentUtils.getPaymentProcessor(herdDocument)).thenReturn(paymentProcessorGroup);
        PowerMockito.when(HerdDocumentUtils.getRunDate(herdDocument)).thenReturn(date);
//        List<String> paymentProcessorList = new ArrayList<>();
//        paymentProcessorList.add("BillDesk");
//        PowerMockito.when(ProcessorGroupLookup.getProcessorsFromGroup(paymentProcessorGroup))
//                .thenReturn(paymentProcessorList);
        String fromDate = "Sat Mar 16 23:59:59 IST 2019";
        String toDate = "Sat Mar 16 23:59:59 IST 2019";
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ROOT);

        List<OverseasTransaction> overseasTransactionList1 = createMockOverseasTransaction();

        Mockito.doReturn(overseasTransactionList1).when(overseasTransactionsStore)
                .queryOverseasTransactionsOnPPTimelineandDates(Mockito.isA(String.class), Mockito.isA(Date.class),
                        Mockito.isA(Date.class));
        Mockito.when(getTransactionsForProcessorGroupActivity.getOverseasTransactions(herdDocument))
                .thenCallRealMethod();
        List<OverseasTransaction> overseasTransactionList = getTransactionsForProcessorGroupActivity
                .getOverseasTransactions(herdDocument);
        assertNotNull(overseasTransactionList);
        // assertEquals(overseasTransactionList.getPaymentProcessorID(), actual);
    }

    private List<OverseasTransaction> createMockOverseasTransaction() {

        Date date = new Date();
        BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(100001);
        List<OverseasTransaction> overseasTransactionList = new ArrayList<OverseasTransaction>();
        OverseasTransaction overseasTransaction = new OverseasTransaction();
        overseasTransaction.setPurchaseID("purchaseID");
        overseasTransaction.setSignatureID("signatureID");
        overseasTransaction.setPaymentProcessorTransactionID("paymentProcessorTransactionID");
        overseasTransaction.setType("Charge");
        overseasTransaction.setSubType("subType");
        overseasTransaction.setTransactionTimestamp(date);
        overseasTransaction.setPaymentMethod("paymentMethod");
        overseasTransaction.setTotalAmount(num);
        overseasTransaction.setOverseasAmount(num);
        overseasTransaction.setCurrency("currency");
        overseasTransaction.setMarketplaceID("marketplaceID");
        overseasTransaction.setOrderMetadata("orderMetadata");
        overseasTransaction.setDisbursementID("disbursementID");
        overseasTransaction.setReconState(1);
        overseasTransaction.setPaymentProcessorID("BillDesk");
        overseasTransaction.setRemittanceFileStatus("remittanceFileStatus");
        overseasTransaction.setCrowID("crowID");
        overseasTransaction.setSource("source");
        overseasTransactionList.add(overseasTransaction);
        return overseasTransactionList;
    }

}
```

In my test file when I mock OverseasTransaction object, it gives me a NullPointerException. Do you have any suggestions about how we can mock this? All the above commented lines in my test indicates the things I tried but they still seem to throw the same error.

StackTrace of error: while executing **canGetOverseasTransactiontest**

N/A

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ingsfundflowservice.activity.GetTransactionsForProcessorGroupActivity.getOverseasTransactions(GetTransactionsForProcessorGroupActivity.java:71)
at com.ingsfundflowservice.activity.GetTransactionsForProcessorGroupActivityTest.canGetOverseasTransactiontest(GetTransactionsForProcessorGroupActivityTest.java:172)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:106)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
```

Comment: My all imports and @prepareForTest annotations are in place. I have also initialized my Mocks in Before using Mockito.init(this).

Comment: First of all, remove `PowerMockito.Mock`, just do `when(overseastransaction.somemethod()).thenReturn(something)`, this is how you define behavior. Second, how are you injecting the mock in your object under test?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create object of Class which for which you are writing the test. i.e. GetTransactionsForProcessorGroupActivity. There is what you can do

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class GetTransactionsForProcessorGroupActivityTest {

  @InjectMocks
  private GetTransactionsForProcessorGroupActivity getTransactionsForProcessorGroupActivity;

  @Mock
  private OverseasTransaction overseastransaction;

  @Test
  public void test() {
    Mockito.when(overseastransaction.somemethod()).thenReturn(something);
  }
}
```

This will make sure that getTransactionsForProcessorGroupActivity is created and  overseastransaction is injected with mock object.

Please note the class annotation **@RunWith**. This make sure that all the properties are injected with mock object properly. Also, you can use Mockito instead of PowerMockito.

Comment: I am using @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) since there are other static methods in this class which I want to mock. Also it is not able to create the object of class GetTransactionsForProcessorGroupActivity which I try to Inject Mocks. Maybe because it extends and abstract class and you can not instantiate an abstract class.

Comment: GetTransactionsForProcessorGroupActivity is a concrete class, so object creation will work (does not matter if its extends an abstract class or implement an interface). One can create object Either directly using new or using Mock. 
Can you update the answer to include the whole code snippet ?
Also, can you paste the complete stack trace of error you are getting.

Comment: Yes, But I am unable to create one. I have update the whole code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a protected setter in the abstract class and then in your `GetTransactionsForProcessorGroupActivity` you can call the setter in the constructor.

Then you just use `@Mock` the field you need to set and then you either use `@InjectMocks` or more suggested to call the constructor in the `@Setup` method including the mock field to be set.